# Getting websocket error every 5 mins -Broken Pipe

Tags: java, websocket, broken-pipe

I am posting data from a python script every 2 sec to a websocket server and UI is trying to read that from the websocket. After every 5 mins the websocket gets down with this error

---

> ERR java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Broken
>   pipe
>
> 2016-01-11T09:51:08.31-0600 [App/0]      ERR    at
>   com.tcs.predix.beta.time.series.ingestion.websocket.WebSocketClient.postToWebSocketServer(WebSoc
>   ketClient.java:76)
>
> *******************Alternate Error*************
>
> 2016-01-13T12:36:58.21-0600 [App/0]      ERR
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The
>   remote endpoint was in state [TEXT_FU LL_WRITING] which is an invalid
>   state for called method
>
> 2016-01-13T12:36:58.21-0600 [App/0]      ERR    at
>   com.tcs.predix.beta.time.series.ingestion.websocket.WebSocketClient.postToWebSocketServer(WebSoc

---

The code where it is breaking is given below. Am I doing something wrong:

---

```
 @Component
public class WebSocketClient
{
     private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(WebSocketClient.class);
    WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();

    @Autowired
    WebSocketConfig endPointConfig;

    @Autowired
    WebsocketEndpoint websocketEndpoint;

    private Map<String,Session> sessions =  new HashMap<String,Session>();

    public Response postToWebSocketServer(String data)
    {
        final Response statusResponse = new Response();

        try
        {
            Session predixWSSession = sessions.get("messages");
             if (predixWSSession == null || !predixWSSession.isOpen()) {
                log.info("Opening New Connection : "+endPointConfig.getPredixWebSocketURI());
                URI predixWebSocketURI = new URI(endPointConfig.getPredixWebSocketURI());
                websocketEndpoint = new WebsocketEndpoint();
                predixWSSession = container.connectToServer(websocketEndpoint, predixWebSocketURI);
                predixWSSession.setMaxIdleTimeout(0);
                sessions.put("messages", predixWSSession);
             }else {
                log.info("Reusing existing Connection");
             }
             predixWSSession.getBasicRemote().sendText(data);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        return statusResponse;
    }

}
```

---

Here is the SERVER Code:

```
@OnMessage
    public void OnMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException {
        // _logger.info("Message : "+message);
        try {
            if ("messages".equalsIgnoreCase(nodeId)) {

                for (Session s : session.getOpenSessions()) {
                    System.out.println(s.getRequestURI().toString());
                    s.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
                }

                //session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
            } else {
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText("SUCCESS");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like java so you may want to add that tag.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out